# Laravel: Load edit form from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to load dinamically my edit form via ajax but I keep getting  a 500 error. My controller is the following:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $task = Task::find($id);
    return view('task.edit', compact('task'));
}
```

My ajax function is the following:

```
$('#show-form').on('click', '#edit-task' ,function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var token = $(this).data('token');
    var id = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        data: {_token: token},
        url: "task/" + id + "/edit",

        success: function (data) {
            ...
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
```

My route [Edited]:

```
Route::resource('task','TaskController', ['only' => ['index', 'store', 'destroy', 'edit', 'show', 'update']]);
```

Comment: show your route

Comment: Added the routes

Comment: What's the error that is shown in the console in the ajax response?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Check your error in  **`storage/logs/laravel.log`** by timestamp

Comment: 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'View [task.edit] not found.

Comment: I CAN'T BELIEVE I WAS MISSING AN 'S' THIS WHOLE TIME

Answer (score -1):

try to change your route to this:

```
Route::resource('/task/{id}','TaskController', ['only' => ['index', 'store', 'destroy', 'edit', 'show', 'update']]);
```

Comment: That makes absolutely zero sense. It's a resource controller.

Comment: yes the /edit was my mistake.. and he is not passing the id in the route @JoelHinz

Comment: Well... I wasn't expecting this to work. I also tried with     `Route::get('task/{id}/edit','TaskController@edit')->name('task.edit');`

Comment: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error